# Why isn't my ball bouncing? NDSolve equations

Tags: differential-equations, physics

Here is my program

```
rownania2 = {m*y''[t] == -m*g - b*y'[t],
    m*x''[t] == -b*x'[t],
  y'[0] == v0*Sin[a],
  y[0] == 0,
  x[0] == 0,
  x'[0] == v0*Cos[a],
  WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> -y'[t]]
  }
rozw30 = NDSolve[rownania2, {x[t], y[t]}, t] /. {m -> 1, g -> 9.81, 
   v0 -> 20, b -> 0.1, a -> 30 Degree}

Animate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[{Evaluate[rozw30[[1, 1, 2]]], 
    Evaluate[rozw30[[1, 2, 2]]]}, {t, 0, g}, PlotRange -> {0, 40}],
  Graphics[
   Point[{Evaluate[rozw30[[1, 1, 2]]] /. t -> g, 
     Evaluate[rozw30[[1, 2, 2]]] /. t -> g}], PointSize[Large]]]
 , {g, 0, 3}]
```

I thought WhenEvent would make my ball and plot bounce at the y[t]=0 but it doesn't. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Your code, when pasted & executed, gives errors.  I think some things are missing.

Comment: Inside NDSolve a time range {t,..,...} is required

Answer (score 1):

`NDSolve` requires to be told over what region to solve for `t`

Solution:

```
rownania2 = {m*y''[t] == -m*g - b*y'[t], m*x''[t] == -b*x'[t], 
  y'[0] == v0*Sin[a], y[0] == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == v0*Cos[a], 
  WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> -y'[t]]}


rozw30 = NDSolve[rownania2, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 30}] /. {m -> 1, 
   g -> 9.81, v0 -> 20, b -> 0.1, a -> 30 Degree}

Animate[Show[
  ParametricPlot[{Evaluate[rozw30[[1, 1, 2]]], 
    Evaluate[rozw30[[1, 2, 2]]]}, {t, 0, g}, PlotRange -> {0, 40}], 
  Graphics[Point[{Evaluate[rozw30[[1, 1, 2]]] /. t -> g, 
     Evaluate[rozw30[[1, 2, 2]]] /. t -> g}], PointSize[Large]]], {g, 
  0, 3}]
```

[image]